# Is 64-bit version of Valgrind able to dig the memory issue of 32-bit program?

Tags: debugging, valgrind

I have 64bit OS and Valgrind installed. And I need to check the memory problem of 32bit program right now. Valgrind can run and produce reprot. But I wonder whether the report generated by valgrind is able to deliver the correct information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Valgrind Documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html),

> Preliminary support for **MacOSX 10.7 and XCode 4**.Both 32- and 64-bit
> processes are supported
>
> There is experimental support for **AIX 5.3**, both 32-bit and 64-bit
> processes.

Also,

**- New configuration flags:**

```
 --enable-only32bit
 --enable-only64bit
```

> By default, on 64 bit platforms (**ppc64-linux**, **amd64-linux**) the build   system will attempt to build a Valgrind which
> supports both 32-bit   and 64-bit executables.  This may not be what
> you want, and you can   override the default behaviour using these
> flags.